# Удалить классы детей

Tags: классы, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить [скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/Tbskw/)

Хотелось бы чтобы после клика на `#qwe` все классы детей `.active` удалились (даже в ie7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('qwe').addEventListener( "click" , function(e){

    for(var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = this.childNodes[i];
        if(child.className)
            child.className = child.className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' )
    }

}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tbskw/1/

Comment: всем спасибо. то что надо

Answer (score 1):

так? http://jsfiddle.net/Tbskw/4/

```
document.getElementById('qwe').addEventListener("click" , function(e){

    var childs = this.childNodes;

    for(var i=0; i < childs.length; i++) {

        if(/.*active.*/.test(childs[i].className)) {

            for(var i2=0; i < childs[i].childNodes.length; i2++) {
                childs[i].childNodes[i2].className = '';
            }  
        }
    }

}, false);
```